# Does this regex do what I think it does?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to do the Python challenge. I'm currently stuck on problem #3. The problem gives you a bunch of text, and tells your to extract any lowercase letter surrounded by exactly 3 uppercase letters. For example: `XXXsXXX` should return `s` as a match.

I'm came up with this regex to perform to look for matches.

```
message = re.findall('(?<=[A-Z]{3})[a-z](?=...[A-Z]{3})', data)
```

What I think this does is:

1. Look for 3 uppercase letters before a lowercase letter.
2. Look for 3 uppercase letters after a lowercase letter.
3. Return said lowercase letter.

Is this right?

Comment: See question. Wonder what the Python Challenge is. Google "python challenge". Click on first result link. Gouge eyes with fork.

Comment: BoltClock -- beware the force of the internet also there is this cool thing about lemons ...

Comment: The challenge itself is actually very good though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is the `...` inside of the lookahead, you are basically looking for any three characters followed by three uppercase characters after the lowercase.  For example:

```
>>> re.findall('(?<=[A-Z]{3})[a-z](?=...[A-Z]{3})', "AAAb123CCC")
['b']
>>> re.findall('(?<=[A-Z]{3})[a-z](?=...[A-Z]{3})', "AAAbCCC")
[]
```

You can fix this issue by just getting rid of the three `...` in the lookahead, however if you need to match exactly three uppercase or lowercase you will need to modify your regex to something like the following:

```
(?<=[^A-Z][A-Z]{3})[a-z](?=[A-Z]{3}[^A-Z])
```

You may need to deal with the special cases of the string starting or ending with a valid pattern.

Comment: This returns the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

I shouldn't have taken comments on merit without checking if they work. Silly of me. your regex does not work as written. You are looking for something like this:

```
message = re.findall(r'[^A-Z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]', data)
```

which would capture the letter you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks to the lookahead and lookbehind, it works! `findall` uses (the same algorithm as) `.group(0)` to get the matched text - things matched by lookahead and lookbehind isn't included in that. Try `re.findall(r'(?<=0)1', '01')` for instance, it's `['1']`.

Comment: I did not know that about findall and directional searching in python. So I suppose yes Bob's does work then.

Comment: @Minisbrunnr: If mine works, why does it return different results than yours? Take a look at yours: http://pastebin.com/ES8qPacw and mine: http://pastebin.com/T91ue76d

Comment: The problem is that the regex can't match "AAAAbAAA", for example. It must be *exactly* 3 upper case letters around the lower case one.

Comment: Actually no this allows for at least three because of the actions of findall. AAAAdAAA matches A(AAAbAAA) which fits the regex.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr:  I think you misunderstand.  The way that python challenge #3 is written (One small letter, surrounded by EXACTLY three big bodyguards on each of its sides), means that AAAAdAAA should *not* match.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalaki -- That was unclear from the question -- edited to be proper

Answer (score 1):

The page contains *only* letters. So the simplest solution is to look for uppercase letters flanked by lowercase characters:

```
message = re.findall('[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]', data)
```

Look-ahead and look-behind is just making it difficult for yourself!